# C# - SSIS : script issue converting a string into a date

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datetime, ssis

I'm using SSIS to create a package which will store data which are in my excel file in a table of my database. One of the column is a DateTime type column. In my script, I'm doing this :

```
Row.BillingDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.F4,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

But it does not work when I launch the script and returns this error :

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime : at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
```

I have no idea about what to do. The Row.BillingDate is a DateTime and the Row.F4 is a string. How can I resolve this?

EDIT : F4 contains a string which represents a date in the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: What is the value of `Row.F4` ?

Comment: It is a string which represents a date. The format of this date is dd/MM/yyyy. For example : 31/12/2012

Comment: Why are you trying to parse hms out of a sting that has no h/m/s?

Comment: Also, what data type is BillingDate in your Data Flow?

Comment: if the format is dd/MM/YYYY , why are you providnig another format to ParseExact function ?

Comment: Well, even if I remove the HH:mm:ss, it is not working. So I tried like this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why use `ParseExact` at all instead of just `Parse` or `TryParse`? If you need do, what format ARE the dates in?

Comment: @billinkc absolutly not. The 2 problems are differents. BillingDate is a DateTime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the format you specify (by `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`) has to match the format the string is in. Try `DateTime.ParseExact(Row.F4.ToString(),"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`.

Also note that you don't specify a time. If the parsing succeeds, the time will evaluate to midnight (0:00:00).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I got the same problem, saying that the string is not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @Traffy I've edited my answer, can you give `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` a go?

Comment: Thnaks again but I tried like that and nothing changes. My F4 data contains a string which represents a date, for example : 31/12/2012

Comment: @Traffy Now I see the issue, you're passing `Row.F4`, which in itself isn't a string. You should use `Row.F4.ToString()`.

Comment: In fact, my row was empty... My fault, sorry, thanks for your advice !